# Is variadic arguments list null-terminated?

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

The title covers my question pretty much completely. For some context - from various sources I know that variadic functions are supposed to have signature where first argument gives information about how many arguments were passed, but after playing around with it a bit i found that `vs_arg` always returns `nullptr` right after the last argument so this code works well (with MS Visual Studio):

```
void func(MClass *t_instance...) {
    std::va_list arguments;
    va_start(arguments, t_instance);
    for (MClass *instance = t_instance; instance != nullptr; instance = va_arg(arguments, MClass *)) {
        std::out << instance->name << std::endl;
    }
    va_end(arguments);
}
```

Of course provided that there is no `nullptr` passed as an argument, is this a valid assumption? I couldn't find that this list is supposed to be null-terminated, but couldn't find the opposite either.

Comment: "first argument" is an implementation detail that you shouldn't rely on.

Comment: I wouldn't count on the `nullptr` right after last argument. AFAIK, a function call (if not using registers or any other technique) pushs argments to stack, space for return value (if any) and the return address. (I don't have the correct order at hand but IMHO it's not that relevant.) So, if there is a `nullptr` "after" the arguments may depend on anything but is not reliable.

Comment: And, btw.shouldn't it be `void func(MClass *t_instance, ...)` (with **`,`**)?

Comment: @Scheff it works either way for me, however I'm not aware of the difference (if it exists)

Comment: I'm not sure. It's a while ago that I fiddled with var args in C. In C++, there are type-safe alternatives. Hence, I didn't use it anymore for longer...

Comment: @Scheff you are correct, just found here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments it's needed for compatibility (but apart from that looks to be optional)

Comment: I would use variadic template `template <typename ... Ts> void func(const Ts*... ts) {((std::out << ts->name << std::endl;), ...);}` instead of C-ellipsis.

Comment: @Scheff: Mixing Variadic template and C-ellipsis can even produce 6 dots: `template <typename ... Ts> void foo(ts......)` (similar to `foo(ts..., ...)`).

Comment: @Jarod42 That looks scaring... ;-) I wonder how the code would look like to decode this (properly).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not a valid assumption that calling `va_arg` at the last parameter will return a null pointer. According to the standard* calling `va_arg` when there are no parameters left, i.e when it is pointing at the last parameter, has undefined behavior. As far as I know there is no way for the program to check when it is at the last parameter, this information must be provided by some other mean.

* The C++ standard refers the behavior of `va_arg` to the C standard, which defines this in section 7.16.1.1 clause 2.

Comment: Yepp. E.g. `printf()` functions track exactly what's given in the format string. If the passed arguments doesn't match the format string - things become worse (U.B.). That's why the `printf()` family is that dangerous (though it's quite powerful and flexible). (+1, of course) ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! `According to the standard` - could you please give the reference of standard version you are referring to? (And paragraph/page number as possible), Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. The most obvious way to check the count on `va_arg` is then to first pass the number of function parameters as a function parameter itself.